# How to access to a state when I'm in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

Is that I need to know how I can access the allContent state in the Root component so, then, show the information.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import ContentCards from './ContentCards.js';
import $ from 'jquery';

export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  search(userSearch) 
  {
    console.log('search in action');
    const urlSearch = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi?api_key=16667866c29ba1bc29e687b4892b8d5c&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=false&query=' + userSearch
    $.ajax({
      url: urlSearch,
      success: (searchs) => {
        console.log('Fetched data succesfully');
        const results = searchs.results;
        var contentSearched = [];

        results.forEach(content => {
          console.log(content);

          content.poster_src = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185' + content.poster_path;
          const contents = < ContentCards key = {
            content.id
          }
          content = {
            content
          }
          />
          contentSearched.push(contents);
        });
        this.setState({
          allContent: contentSearched
        });
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error('Failed to fetch data');
      }
    });
  }

  searchChangeHandler(event) {
    const userSearch = event.target.value;
    this.search(userSearch);
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "navbar-end" >
      <
      div className = "control has-icons-left has-icons-right" >
      <
      input className = "input"
      onChange = {
        this.searchChangeHandler.bind(this)
      }
      placeholder = "search ..." / >
      <
      span className = "icon is-small is-right" >
      <
      i className = "fas fa-search" > < /i> <
      /span> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```

It is assumed that the Root component can access the allContent state but I do not succeed in doing so. The function that has allContent is to be able to save all the data that you use between, for example, if the user searches for the Avatar movie, a table related to all Avatar content will be shown.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {NavBar} from './NavBar';

export class Root extends React.Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div className='container'>
        <div><NavBar/></div>
        <hr/>
        {this.props.allContent}
       </div>
   );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question the first time.

You want the parent to be able to access the child state right?

You'd to have the child's state defined in the root and passed down as props.
Something along these lines

```js
class Child extends React.Component
{
  constructor
  {
    this.state = this.props.passedState || {};
    this.upDateState = this.upDateState.bind(this);
  }
  
  updateState(newState)
  {
    //Updates the state of parent, adding child state
    this.props.passToParent(newState);
  }
  
  render()
  {
    return('some stuff')
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.state = {
      childState : {}.
    }
    this.passToChild = this.passToChild.bind(this);
  }
  
  passToChild(newChildState)
  {
    let currentState = {...this.state};
    currentState.childState = newChildState;
    return this.setState(currentState);
  }
  
  render()
  {
    return(
      <Child
        passState={this.state.childState},
        passToParrent={this.passToChild}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, technically what I want to do is that within the Root component access the state of allContent that defined it in the this.setState ({allContent: contentSearched}) that belongs to the SearchBar component.

Comment: Yes but the search bar has it's own state, you're wanting the root to be able to use that state as well right? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: That's the problem, when you say `this.setState`, you're setting the state of the `SearchBar`. But your `Root` has to have a state as well. You have to pass a method from `Root` to `SearchBar`. That method has to set the state of root

Comment: Also, is it NavBar or SearchBar?

Comment: In the SearchBar component is where the allContent state is.

Comment: But in root, is it supposed to use `NavBar` or `SearchBar`?

Comment: The root component is the schema to show the navbar and the content.
In this case the content would be what I want to show , which is what is saved in the state of allContent.

Comment: I just added {this.props.allContent} to see if I could access the information, but that is not the case.

Comment: I used super agent instead because it's cleaner and smaller than jquery. It's a nice library. Jquery should be avoided

Comment: I can send to you the github link?

Comment: Negative. Sorry I have other things to be working on. The information I provided should be more than enough

Comment: No problem, tomorrow I'll be working on it.
I think that with the examples you gave me, it's more than enough.

Comment: Groovy, mark the question as answered if you think so :D